# addVectorLayer without popup dialog

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

The below Python code opens "select vector layer..." dialogbox. Selecting one or more layers works nicely.

[image]

How can we specify the layers programmatically using Python and then skipping the dialogbox? The dialogbox becomes annoying very quickly and it is the same layers that is needed.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer('C:\tmp\enc\NN1234.00','tbd','ogr')
```

Using QGis 2.18.15

Comment: Can you insert an image in your question showing this dialog box?

Comment: What kind of layer are you trying to add?

Comment: In general we would like to add LineString and Polygon. At the moment I'd like to add "COALNE" layer.